# Fill in a form box in Python

Tags: python, html

I'm looking to fill in this form box on my website through python.
http://hughchalmers.com/devs/stackoverflow is the link. That has a basic text box and submit button. When you enter something in there, it will appear in http://hughchalmers.com/devs/stackoverflow/KL78.txt. How would I make a python script that will enter info in there then submit it, using requests module? I've tried this

```
import requests
text = raw_input()

url = 'http://hughchalmers.com/devs/stackoverflow'
query = {'text': text}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Hugh'}
res = requests.post(url, data=query, headers=headers)
```

but it doesn't work. No errors, just doesn't send.

Comment: I see that you're not posting to the URL that the actual form posts to. It posts to `send.php`. Perhaps you can try posting to that instead?

Comment: But the form box is in the url in my code

Comment: Oh no, sorry. Your way worked. Thank you

Comment: I'll put my comment in as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HTML of the page (which now appears to be a broken link), I could see that the form was POSTing to `send.php`. The code in your question is instead posting straight to `http://hughchalmers.com/devs/stackoverflow`, instead of to `http://hughchalmers.com/devs/stackoverflow/send.php`.

Simply change your code to POST to that location instead and you should be fine.